# SSRS how to add a comment

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I would like to know how to add a comment on an SSRS report after viewing a report, please not i am using SSRS in a Native mode not in a Sharepoint Intergrated mode, is it Possible?

Comment: What to you mean by "add a comment?" I suspect what you are asking for is not built-in functionality.

Comment: Jamie, what i mean is, let us say you view a report that is deployed on the report server, but you would like to add a comment after viewing the report, and onother person views the same report with the comment that was added by the first viewer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSRS allows for a description field on deployed reports that might help you some. But otherwise, SSRS doesn't directly support what you are describing.

SSRS doesn't directly support a method for text user input other than the user parameters. So finding a way to enter a comment would probably be the biggest challenge to building your own solution around SSRS. But you can run arbitrary SQL to store that comment and then it can be displayed on future reports.